# Quadratic and Greatest Integer Function

Tags: functions, quadratics

**If both roots of the quadratic equation** **$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - 1$** lie in **$(-2, 2)$** **then which of the following can be** **$[a]$** **?**

**$[a]$** **denotes greatest Integer function of** **$a$**

**$$A. -1$$**

**$$B. 1$$**

**$$C. 2$$**

**$$D. 3$$**

I have solve it using graphs:

The graph will intersect the x-axis somewhere between $-2$ and $2$. Hence we can conclude that $f(2)$ and $f(-2)$ will be greater than zero.

Now there will be two quadratic equation in $a$ and we will get $4$ values of $a$ I.e. $-3, -1 , 3 ,1$. From these values the answer should be opton **$D.$** but the answer is given as option **$A.$**

Kindly help.

Comment: HINT: write the function as $(x-a)^2-1$, so that its shape is easy to recognize.

Comment: What does "$[a]$" mean?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 - 1=0$$ $$\implies x^2 - 2ax + a^2 = 1$$
$$\implies (x-a)^2=1$$ $$\implies x-a=\pm1$$
$$\implies x=a+1,a-1$$

Now it is given that both the roots lie between $-2$ and $2$.

Therefore, we have that $$-2 < a+1< 2$$ $$\implies -3 < a < 1\tag1$$ and $$-2 < a-1< 2$$ $$\implies -1 < a< 3 \tag2$$
This means from $(1)$ and $(2)$ that $-1 < a < 1$.
So $[a]$ should be either $0$ or $-1$.
Since $0$ is not in the option but $-1$ is, so the answer should be $(A)$.

Comment: Is there a way to conclude answer from the method that I've used?

Comment: @user109256 Your conclusions are wrong. The graph actually cuts the x-axis twice between $-2$ and $2$ since it is a quadratic equation. So $f(2)$ and $f(-2)$ are either both positive or both negative. Still the method doesn't seem to help anyway.

Comment: Suppose if the question was a bit different I mean if we were not able to for something symmetrical to $(x-a)$ there it would have been tedious to solve it. What about that type?

Comment: Depends upon the equation. You don't have any general procedure for such questions.

Comment: More and more practice will help. Thank you